# NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Generated rails 4.2.0 app and added activerecord-postgis-adapter and edited the database.yml file accordingly.

But now when I do `rake db:create`, it blows with the error:

```
± be rake db:create                                                                                                         2.1.0
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition
/Users/millisami/Railsapps/showme/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/millisami/Railsapps/showme/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/millisami/Railsapps/showme/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the `activerecord-postgis-adapter` gem is [not yet compatible with ActiveRecord 4.2](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/pull/145).

Either use the standard `pg` gem (that is supported natively by ActiveRecord), or downgrade to 4.1.

Comment: Latest update from the link above is that there is a beta available for activerecord-postgis-adapter which fixes this:     

gem "activerecord-postgis-adapter", "3.0.0.beta1"

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.0.0 of `activerecord-postgis-adapter` has been released. It supports ActiveRecord 4.2.

`gem "activerecord-postgis-adapter"`

https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter

https://rubygems.org/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by ob1 in the comment of the accepted answer, at the time of this post, the postgis adapter has a beta version which supports ActiveRecord 4.2. This is the text from the link provided by Simone Carletti:

> This branch is released as 3.0.0.beta1. Test with:
>
> gem "activerecord-postgis-adapter", "3.0.0.beta1" There are
>   significant changes to the PostgreSQL adapter in ActiveRecord 4.2, and
>   it is extremely cumbersome to support prior versions in a single code
>   base. Therefore, instead of having conditional support for prior
>   versions of ActiveRecord, this adapter will only support ActiveRecord
>   4.2 and later in the master branch and version 3.0.
>
> activerecord-postgis-adapter version 2.x will continue to support
>   ActiveRecord 4.0 and 4.1.
>
> activerecord-postgis-adapter version 3.x will support ActiveRecord 4.2
>   and later.